# Bigquery: WHERE clause using column from outside the subquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

New to Bigquery, and googling could not really point me to the solution of the problem.

I am trying to use a where clause in a subquery to filter and pick the latest row for each other row in the main query. In postgres I'd normally do it like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_a AS a
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    (
        SELECT
            score,
            CONCAT( "AB", id ) AS id 
        FROM
            table_b AS b
        WHERE
            id = a.company_id
            and 
            b.date < a.date
        ORDER BY
            b.date DESC 
        LIMIT
            1
    ) ON true

WHERE
    id LIKE 'AB%'

ORDER BY
    createdAt DESC
```

so this would essentially run the subquery against each row and pick the latest row from table B based on a given row's date from table A.

So if table `A` would have a row

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 2021-05-XX |

and table `B`:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2022-01-XX | 99 |
| 12 | 2021-02-XX | 98 |
| 12 | 2020-03-XX | 97 |
| 12 | 2019-04-XX | 96 |

It would have joined only the row with `2021-02-XX` to table `a`.

---

In another example, with

Table `A`:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 2021-01-XX |

Table `B`:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 2022-01-XX | 99 |
| 15 | 2021-02-XX | 98 |
| 15 | 2020-03-XX | 97 |
| 15 | 2019-04-XX | 96 |

it would join only the row with `date: 2020-03-XX, value: 97`.

Hope that is clear, not really sure how to write this query to work

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please explain your `Id` column in Table B, because those `id` values are not unique identifiers...

Comment: Some of your logic doesn't make sense for the values you are wanting to return.  For example  b.date > a.updatedAt then a limit to get the most recent, but you say in the first example the table_a value should be 2021-05-XX while the table_b value should be 2021-02-XX, similarly with your second example table_a = 2021-01-XX , table_b = 2022-03-XX.  In both cases there are more recent values.  Is there additional logic that you are applying?

Comment: @Dai ID is identifier of customer, where can have multiple value entries but only one for each date, so ID is not unique.

Comment: @DanielZagales I think mod editing my post (when formatting the tables) changed my dates of years.. let me edit it

Comment: @DanielZagales previously i had it by year

Comment: @mark124_2 Yes, I changed your dates from truncated `2022-01` (which is a month-year, not a full `date`) to a fake-date-for-illustration (`2022-01-XX`). My apologies if that was an unwanted change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace some of your correlated sub-select logic with a simple join and qualify statement.

Try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
  ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.date < a.date
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY b.date desc) = 1
```

With your sample data it produces:
[image]

This should work for both truncated dates (YYYY-MM) as well as full dates (YYYY-MM-DD)

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work for your requirements

```
    WITH
  latest_record AS (
  SELECT
    a.id,
    value,b.date, a.createdAt
  FROM
    `gcp-project-name.data-set-name.A` AS a
  JOIN
    `gcp-project-name.data-set-name.B` b
  ON
    ( a.id = b.id
      AND b.date < a.updatedAt )
  ORDER BY
    b.date DESC
  LIMIT
    1 )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  latest_record
```

I ran this with table A as

[image]

and table B as

[image]

and get result

[image]