# BigQuery: 'join lateral' alternative for referencing value in subquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that holds append-only data - each time an entity is updated a new version of it is inserted. Each entity has its unique ID and each entry has a timestamp of when it was inserted.

When querying for the latest version of the entity, I order by rank, partition by `id`, and select the most recent version.

I want to take advantage of this and chart the progression of these entities over time. For example, I would like to generate a row for each day since Jan. 1st, with a summary of the entities as they were on that day. In postgres, I would do:

```sql
select
  ...
from generate_series('2022-01-01'::timestamp, '2022-09-01'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) query_date
left join lateral (
  select *
  from (
    with snapshot as (
      select distinct on (id) *
      from table
      where "createdOn" <= query_date
      order by id, "createdOn" desc
    )
```

This basically behaves like a for-each, having each subquery run once for each `query_date` (day, in this instance) which I can reference in the `where` clause. Each subquery then filters the data so that it only uses data up to a certain time.

I know that I can create a saved query for the "subquery" logic and then schedule a prefill to run once for each day over the timeline, but I would like to understand how to write an exploratory query.

EDIT 1

Using a correlated subquery is a step in the right direction, but does not work when the subquery needs to join with another table (another append-only table holding a related entity).

So this works:

```sql
select
  day
  , (
    select count(*)
    from `table` t
    where date(createdOn) < day
  )
from unnest((select generate_date_array(date('2022-01-01'), current_date(), interval 1 day) as day)) day
order by day desc
```

But if I need the subquery to join with another table, like in:

```sql
select
  day
  , (
    select as struct *
    from (
      select
        id
        , status
        , rank() over (partition by id order by createdOn desc) as rank
      from `table1`
      where date(createdOn) < day
      qualify rank = 1
    ) t1
    left join (
      select
        id
        , other
        , rank() over (partition by id order by createdOn desc) as rank
      from `table2`
      where date(createdOn) < day
      qualify rank = 1
    ) t2 on t2.other = t1.id
  )
from unnest((select generate_date_array(date('2022-01-01'), current_date(), interval 1 day) as day)) day
order by day desc
```

I get an error saying `Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN`. Another SO question about that error ([Avoid correlated subqueries error in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040472/avoid-correlated-subqueries-error-in-bigquery)) solves the issue by moving the correlated query to a join in the top query - which misses what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while, but I figured out a way to do this using the answer in [Bigquery: WHERE clause using column from outside the subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73825482/bigquery-where-clause-using-column-from-outside-the-subquery?rq=1).

Basically, it requires to flip the order of the queries, here's how it's done:

```sql
select *
from (
  select *
  from `table1` t1
  JOIN (select day from unnest((select generate_timestamp_array(timestamp('2022-01-01'), current_timestamp(), interval 1 day) as day)) day) day
    ON (t1.createdOn) < day.day
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY day, t1.id ORDER BY t1.createdOn desc) = 1
)
left join (
  select
    * -- aggregate here
  from (
    SELECT
      id, other, createdOn
    FROM `table2` t2
    JOIN (select day from unnest((select generate_timestamp_array(timestamp('2022-01-01'), current_timestamp(), interval 1 day) as day)) day) day
      ON (t2.createdOn) < day.day
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY day, t2.id ORDER BY t2.createdOn desc) = 1
  ) snapshot
  group by rs.other, day
) t2 on t2.other = t1.id and t2.day = t1.day
group by t1.day
```